# How to modify a Wiki Site Page  layout

Tags: wiki, 2007

We are looking to see if we can leverage a WIKI to advertise sections of our governance plan to the end user community.   Right now with a WIKI we get the option to add web parts to the bottom of the layout.   The desired design would be to design a layout that would have a right column that would be a zone of other Web Parts.  For instance, a LVWP that would contain contacts and/or FAQS, an image web part etc.   We just want more flexibility with layout.  I am thinking we could add zones with Designer etc but wanted to see if there was something more obvious.

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 1):

I'd say if you're using a Wiki *site* then I'd create a new master page and be done with it.

If you've just got a wiki *library* on an existing site, it looks like you might be able to get what you want by creating a template for the wiki and adding in the webpart zones. You can find this in SPD by accessing the properties of the wiki library.

Cheers
Mike

Answer (score 1):

I Know it's not really helpful to you now, but SharePoint 2010 has a really neat button on the ribbon that lets you change the page layout to one of the following:

-One Column
-One column with right sidebar
-Two Columns
-Two Columns with header
-Two Columns with header and footer
-Three columns
-three with header
-three with header and footer.

But as Mike H said, if SharePoint 07 it's into SPD you must go!